# Hadoop reducer raw output

Tags: hadoop, binary

I have a hadoop task written in Python.

I'm trying to output result as raw binary data, but the data I get are "corrupted". Looks like standard outputter doesn't work with binary data well.

Is there any way to fix it **without** writing own outputter in Java?

Answer (score 0):

Lost hope to find an answer, I've implemented my own writer in Java.